# How to split value column and append it into dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, fillna

**Example Problem**

```
df =
       variant    variant_param    variant_new
  0        car    petro / young            Nan
  1       bike     fred / trail            NaN
  2     bottle              Nan            NaN
```

Then is it possible to convert it using `df.loc[:,'variant':'variant_param'].fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)['variant_param']`
But from my code I only get like this

```
df =
       variant    variant_param    variant_new
  0        car    petro / young  petro / young
  1       bike     fred / trail    red / trail
  2     bottle              Nan         bottle
```

However, I need my dataframe into like this

```
df =
       variant    variant_param    variant_new
  0        car    petro / young          petro
  1        car    petro / young          young
  2       bike     fred / trail           fred
  3       bike     fred / trail          trail
  4     bottle              Nan         bottle
```

Comment: should `variant_param` be `gas` at line `2` in your data?

Comment: @QuangHoang Okay, thank you for your correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
df['new'] = df['variant_param'].str.split(' / ')
df = df.explode('new')
```

Comment: Thank you!, how about if there is NaN in variant_param?